# Mailto introduced in form

Tags: javascript, html

How can I use the mailto in form's action so it sends to an email the user is going to fill, and the body of the mail is the form itself (method post)?

```html
<form name="miFormulario" onsubmit="return validateForm()" action="mailto:$thisone" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
  
  <input type="email" value="@" name="thisone" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$" size="40" maxlength="100" required>
  
  </form>
```

Something like this

Comment: This is a hack from the late 1990s that never worked as intended. It isn't worth the effort, really.

Comment: Don't. Just don't even bother trying. [mailto: doesn't work well for form actions](http://isolani.co.uk/articles/mailto.html)